Characterize the following code segment as tightly as can be inferred using Big-O
I am having an argument about what is the complexity that most tightly fits the following code:
‘’’while (n < 1000000)
n = n*2;’’’
I argue that it is O(log n). The worst case, to me, is if n were a decimal, which you could theoretically make infinitely small, such as 0.0000000001, etc.
He argues that the answer is O(1) since it is limited by 1,000,000 by how large it can grow. Which I would understand but my professor never specified that the n had to be >= 1.
Again the code provided is all that was provided, no additional description was added. We did however both agree that we would not set N to a negative meaning it would not infinitely run.
What do you all think is the complexity of the code? I just want to make sure I have this understood for similar questions in the future

negative meaning it would not infinitely run evaluate some iterations starting with a) 2 and b) -0.999 and c) -2 and reconsider. The instructor may have mentioned $n$ to be a natural number.
